# Mistakenly created a new branch and git won't pull

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-checkout

We have 2 branches. One is **live** and the other is **admin**. We just moved to a paid github account and I was working on **live**.

After git push, when i type "git branch", only **live** shows up. I don't know why. Mistakenly, i typed "git branch admin" instead of "git checkout admin" and I think this created a clone of the **live**.

I can't access the **admin** branch anymore! What should I do?

Comment: You most likely want to delete the `admin` branch you created by mistake (run `git branch -d admin` for that), then fetch the `admin` branch from the remote (run `git fetch`), then check out the remote-tracking branch as a local branch (run `git checkout admin`).

Comment: Could you kindly post this as answer? It's working now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If a branch `admin` already existed, then if you had typed

```
git branch admin
```

You should get the error:

```
fatal: A branch named 'admin' already exists.
```

This suggests that perhaps you never pulled the branch to your machine, or deleted it in some other way. Why not just pull the branch again from GitHub?

```
git fetch origin admin    
git checkout -b admin origin/admin
```

Comment: I got this when I do `fetch origin admininterface`
 * branch            admininterface -> FETCH_HEAD. However, when i do the checkout, it says, "A branch named 'admin' already exists." When i enter git branch, `Already on 'admin'`. The codes are those of `live`. What did I missed?

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the `admin` and then use `git checkout admin`. This pulled the correct one. Thank You :)